# convertir array a cierto formato

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

tengo 2 arrays en javascript que necesitos convertilos a un formato en especifico, el formato actual de esos 2 array es:

```
"diavalor": [
            "15",
            "27",
            "44",
            "63",
            "-1",
            "8",
            "9",
            "22"
        ],
        "diafecha": [
            "2018-08-30",
            "2018-08-30",
            "2018-08-30",
            "2018-08-30",
            "2018-08-30",
            "2018-08-30",
            "2018-08-30",
            "2018-08-30"
        ]
```

y el formato que necesito es:

```
var data = [
            [1, 20],
            [2, 40],
            [3, 25],
            [4, 45],
            [5, 25],
            [6, 50],
            [7, 35],
            [8, 60],
            [9, 30]
          ];
```

y no se como llegar a dicho a formato, espero puedan ayudarme

---

actualizacion mi problema esta en el formato ya que lo que hago:

```
var array=respuesta.humedad.diavalor;
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           data[i]=[[it,parseInt(array[i])]];
          it+=1;
        }
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data2);
```

da un formato distinto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo como conviertes "15" y "2018-08-30" en "1,20".

Comment: es solo un ejemplo del formato que quiero, la idea seria [15,2018-08-30] para asi lograr el formato, ya que haciendo algo asi data2=[[1,2]]; al usar la variable, la libreria no me lo toma como formato, ya que fallo en el for donde mi array toma un formato distinto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con algo como esto.

```
var valores = {
  "diavalor": [
    "15",
    "27",
    "44",
    "63",
    "-1",
    "8",
    "9",
    "22"
  ],
  "diafecha": [
    "2018-08-30",
    "2018-08-30",
    "2018-08-30",
    "2018-08-30",
    "2018-08-30",
    "2018-08-30",
    "2018-08-30",
    "2018-08-30"
  ]
};

var listaFinal = [];

var dias = valores.diavalor;
var fechas = valores.diafecha;

for (let i = 0; i < dias.length; i++) {
  const elemento = [ dias[i], fechas[i] ];
  listaFinal.push(elemento);      
}

console.log(listaFinal);
```

Este es el resultado en consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me funciono, gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una forma bastante corta usando `.map()`. De paso puedes castear como integers los strings del primer array agregando `+` si quieres.

```js
var obj = {"diavalor": ["15","27","44","63","-1","8","9","22"],
"diafecha": ["2018-08-30","2018-08-30","2018-08-30","2018-08-30","2018-08-30","2018-08-30","2018-08-30","2018-08-30"]}


var arr = obj.diavalor.map((e,i)=>[+e,obj.diafecha[i]])

console.log(arr)
```

Esto es asumiendo que la relación entre los dos arrays está en el orden de los mismos, y no en algo externo. En dicho caso sería obviamente diferente la implementación.